# Unable to find element in stand alone browser

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium-webdriver

I have tried many different formats and am unable to locate the link that I need to click using xpath.  Please help me learn the magic of xpath...

```
IWebElement TCE = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[*/text()='Recently Visited']/child::a[@title='Time Clock Entry']"));
            TCE.Click();
```

The code in the webpage for the link is as follows...

```
<div id="RecentlyVisitedWidget" class="recentlyVisitedWidget">
   <h2 id="ctl00_12_12_RecentlyVisitedLabel">Recently Visited</h2>
      <ul class="recentlyVisitedLinks">
         <li>
            <span id="ctl00_12_12_Repeater1_ctl00_link">
               <a title="Time Clock Entry" onclick="recentlyVisitedSelect('pages/VIEW/UTMEntry.aspx?USParams=PK=ESS!MenuID=2147!PageRerId=2147!ParentRerId=72','72','2147','2147', false, false, 'Time Clock Entry', true)" href="#"> Time Clock Entry</a>
            </span>
         </li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

I am able to accomplish this using the following code within a webBrowser Control in a form.

```
HtmlElement link = (from HtmlElement elem in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a")
                                    where elem.InnerHtml == "Time Clock Entry"
                                    select elem).ElementAt(0);
                link.InvokeMember("Click");
```

I am unable to find this link when trying to do this in a stand alone browser such as IE or Firefox.
I have tried searching by CssSelector, linkText, Partial linkText,  link, XPath, and the Id all returning a message telling me that the element could not be found.

Any ideas on why I would be able to locate this element in a webBrowser Control but not in a browser?

Comment: What are you looking for, the <a> link?

Comment: @OldProgrammer I have tried the <a> link, the linkText, the Partial linkText, the XPath, the CssSelector, and the Id.  None of them have worked.  I always get a message saying that the element could not be found.

Answer (score 1):

Your XPath should be something like this

```
//div[@id='RecentlyVisitedWidget']//a[@title='Time Clock Entry']
```

or

```
//div[h2[text()='Recently Visited']]//a[@title='Time Clock Entry']
```

Comment: Those did not work.  I also tried //div[text()='Recently Visited']//a[@title='Time Clock Entry']

Comment: @SeanConnelly I posted both xpath after I tested with your sample in question. So sorry, That is all I can do with the given information.

Comment: Thank you.  I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be an XPath?

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("ul.recentlyVisitedLinks a[title='Time Clock Entry']")).click();
```

I would avoid XPaths, when possible, because they are more error prone and slower.

Comment: Thank you for the idea.  Unfortunately, I have been trying to do this for almost four months now.  I can click on this link programmaticly in a webBrowser Control but can not click on a button in the next page due to frames and I can not click on this link in this page in a standalone browser.  I have tried dozens of methods.  About to just drop this project, even though it would simplify my job.  Thank you all for the help.

Comment: I do have a question... Why is there an opening bracket before title but no closing bracket?

Comment: ...because I typo'd :)... fixed.

Comment: Fixed now... I was mid-edit and got pulled away. Should have done the edit and *then* said it was fixed. Sorry. :)

Comment: Thank you. I am still receiving a message that the element can not be found.  I have posted a new question that may help... I hope.  The title of the question is "Unable to locate element in stand alone browser".  Would you mind looking at that one.  It may help with this one...